# Distinguishing between terms of different domains

Tags: list, dictionary, nlp, ontology

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to take a list of terms and distinguish which domain they are coming from. For example "intestine" would be from the anatomical domain while the term "cancer" would be from the disease domain. I am getting these terms from different ontologies such as DOID and FMA (they can be found at bioportal.bioontology.org)

**The problem:**

I am having a hard time realizing the best way to implement this. Currently I am naively taking the terms from the ontologies DOID and FMA and taking difference of any term that is in the FMA list which we know is anatomical from the DOID list (which contains terms that may be anatomical such as colon carcinoma, colon being anatomical and carcinoma being disease).

**Thoughts:**

I was thinking that I can get root words, prefixes, and postfixes, for the different term domains and try and match it to the terms in the list. Another idea is to take more information from their ontology such as meta data or something and use this to distinguish between the terms.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first run, you'll probably have the best luck with bigrams. As an initial hypothesis, diseases are usually noun phrases, and usually have a very English-specific structure where `NP -> N N`, like "liver cancer", which means roughly the same thing as "cancer of the liver." Doctors tend not to use the latter, while the former should be caught with bigrams quite well.

Use the two ontologies you have there as starting points to train some kind of bigram model. Like Rcynic suggested, you can count them up and derive probabilities. A [Naive Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) would work nicely here. The features are the bigrams; classes are anatomy or disease. [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) has Naive Bayes built in. The "naive" part means, in this case, that all your bigrams are independent of each other. This assumption is fundamentally false, but it works well in a lot of circumstances, so we pretend it's true.

This won't work perfectly. As it's your first pass, you should be prepared to probe the output to understand how it derived the answer it came upon and find cases that failed on. When you find trends of errors, tweak your model, and try again.

I wouldn't recommend WordNet here. It wasn't written by doctors, and since what you're doing relies on precise medical terminology, it's probably going to add bizarre meanings. Consider, from `nltk.corpus.wordnet`:

```
>>> livers = reader.synsets("liver")
>>> pprint([l.definition() for l in livers])
[u'large and complicated reddish-brown glandular organ located in the upper right portion of the abdominal cavity; secretes bile and functions in metabolism of protein and carbohydrate and fat; synthesizes substances involved in the clotting of the blood; synthesizes vitamin A; detoxifies poisonous substances and breaks down worn-out erythrocytes',
u'liver of an animal used as meat',
u'a person who has a special life style',
u'someone who lives in a place',
u'having a reddish-brown color']
```

Only one of these is really of interest to you. As a null hypothesis, there's an 80% chance WordNet will add noise, not knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach - what precision and recall is it getting you? If you setup a test case now, then you can track your progress as you apply more sophisticated methods.

I don't know what initial set you are dealing with - but one thing to try is to get your hands on annotated documents(maybe use mechanical turk). The documents need to be tagged as the domains you're looking for - anatomical or disease.

then count and divide will tell you how likely a word you encounter is to belong to a domain. With that the next step and be to tweak some weights.

Another approach (going in a whole other direction) is using WordNet. I don't know if it will be useful for exactly your purposes, but its a massive ontology - so it might help.

Python has bindings to use Wordnet via nltk.

from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

wn.synsets('cancer')

gives output = [Synset('cancer.n.01'), Synset('cancer.n.02'), Synset('cancer.n.03'), Synset('cancer.n.04'), Synset('cancer.n.05')]

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn

Let us know how it works out.